# Independence of $X$ and $2X$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Are these two random variables independent? Unfortunately, I don't know probability theory enough to answer this question. I know for a fact that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables and $g$,$h$ are measurable functions, then $g(X)$ and $h(Y)$ are independent as well. However, I don't know if that can be used here.

I ran into this question in my work, where someone asked if the following moment generating function was valid:
$$M_{X}(t)M_{X}(2t) $$
and stated that this was, indeed, a valid moment generating function for a random variable $X+Y$ where $Y$ follows the same distribution of $2X$.

But is it true that you *can* write the moment generating function of $X+Y$ as such? (Basically, I doubt that $X$ and $2X$ are independent.)

**My main question**: Does there exist a random variable $X$ such that you can write the moment generating function of $X + 2X$ as stated above (assuming the MGFs exist)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've written your question in a rather confused and confusing way.  In your question you refer to "a random variable $X+Y$ where $Y$ follows the same distribution of $2X$."  But elsewhere in your question, you mention the question of whether $X$ and $2X$ are independent, which is quite a different matter.

So:

- $X$ and $2X$ are not independent except when $X$ is constant;

but

- That has nothing to do with questions about $X+Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $Y$ has the same distribution as $2X$.

Let's address the second question:
\begin{align}
M_{X+Y}(t) = \mathbb E(e^{t(X+Y)}) & = \mathbb E(e^{tX} e^{tY}) \\[10pt]
& = \mathbb E(e^{tX})\mathbb E(e^{tY}) \text{ by independence} \\[10pt]
& = M_X(t) \mathbb E(e^{t(2X)}) \tag 1 \\[10pt]
& = M_X(t)\mathbb E(e^{(2t)X}) \\[10pt]
& = M_X(t) M_X(2t).
\end{align}

The equality in $(1)$ is true because expected values depend only on the distribution.

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. I thought that moment generating functions of random variables can be factored out completely (as in the question) if and only if the random variables are independent.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for the mgf of a sum $X+Y$ is correct when $X$ and $Y$ are **independent**.

Apart from  a few degenerate examples, $X$ and $2X$ are **not** independent.

For instance, toss a fair coin, and let $X=1$ if we get a head, and $X=0$ otherwise.

Then $\Pr(X=1\cap 2X=0)=0$. But $\Pr(X=1)\nee 0$, and $\Pr(2X=0)\ne 0$, so 
$$\Pr(X=1\cap 2X=0)\ne \Pr(X=1)\Pr(2X=0).$$
The above was a **formal** showing of non-independence. At the more informal level, if we know that $X=1$, we know a great deal, indeed everything, about $2X$.

**Edit:** For the question about whether the mgf of $X+2X$ is **ever** the product of the mgf, let $X=0$ with probability $1$.

Comment: Could you perhaps link me to an example?

Comment: Shreve (*Stochastic Calculus for Finance*) states that if you can write the joint moment generating function $\mathbb{E}\left[e^{uX+vY}\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[e^{uX}\right] \cdot \mathbb{E}\left[e^{vY}\right]$, then $X$ and $Y$ are independent. However, the proof is "beyond the scope of this text."

Answer (score 0):

Think of independence as "Having informations on $X$ does not give me any information on $Y$".

This is clearly not the case, if you know that $X = 2$, you **also** know that $2X = 4$, so they are not independent.

The formal definition for independence of $X$ and $Y$ is

$P(X \in A, Y \in B) = P(X \in A) \cdot P(Y \in B)$  for all $A, B$.

The choice of $A, B$ depends on the probability space on which $X$ is defined, but to make things easy, suppose $X$ is a real random variable (let's say a gaussian).

Then if you take $A = [0, 1], B = [3, 4]$, you know

$P(X \in A, 2X \in B) = 0$ (because if $X$ is in $A$, then $2X$ is **not** in $B$ and vice versa).
But $P(X \in A) \cdot P(X \in B) \neq 0$

Comment: Yes, what you say makes sense. Could you read the edit I posted?